# php deep cloning still alters value

Tags: php, codeigniter, object, clone

I have the following function:

```
$results_array = array();

        foreach($results as $row) {

            $t = time();
            $t = $this->load->library('Funding_Opportunity_L', '', $t);

            // Starting to build object
            $t->opp_name = $row->name;
            $t->description = $row->description;



            // Allocate funder
            $t->funder = $this->funders_model->getFromId($row->funder);
            echo $t->funder->name . " ";
            // Allocate duration
            $t->date_range = $this->date_range_model->getFromId($row->duration);

            // Allocate career stage
            $t->career_stages = $this->career_stage_model->getAllMatchingOpportunities($row->id);

            // Allocate type
            $t->types = $this->type_model->getAllMatchingOpportunities($row->id);
            $tt = clone $t;
            array_push($results_array, clone $t);

            unset($t);

        }

        $r = $results_array[0];
        echo $r->funder->name;

        $r = $results_array[1];
        echo $r->funder->name;
        return $results_array;
```

which echoes two distinct results while inside the foreach loop (first echo statement) but then echoes only the latter value when reading the value from the array. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong as I'm cloning the object rather than adding it by reference and unsetting the object?

Comment: Are you using CodeIgniter? Tag the question properly.

Comment: Done! Tagged appropriately

Comment: On the most recent version of CodeIgniter, `$this->load->library()` returns `$this->load` which is an object of type `Loader`. You don't need to load the library on each loop. Loading it once before the loop is enough (it is not loaded multiple times, anyway). It seems you only store information in `$t`. Isn't it better to initialize it with `$t = new stdClass();`?